# "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()" in Wamp, drivers installed

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, sql-server-2008, wamp

I've got the following code in my Wordpress file:

```
$sql_server_2008 = sqlsrv_connect(
    '$ip',
    array(
        'Database'=>'$database_name',
        'UID'=>'$uid',
        'PWD'=>'$password'
    )
);
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

I'm running Wamp with PHP 5.6.25, so I've installed the 5.6 versions of the SQL Server drivers. From PHP.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

and they're showing as active in the Wamp UI:

[image: Screenshot showing the active extensions]

So why isn't it working?

**EDIT: They're not showing up in loaded extensions.**

```
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions (); 
print_r($extensions);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Core [1] => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => ctype [4] => date [5] => ereg [6] => filter [7] => ftp [8] => hash [9] => iconv [10] => json [11] => mcrypt [12] => SPL [13] => odbc [14] => pcre [15] => Reflection [16] => session [17] => standard [18] => mysqlnd [19] => tokenizer [20] => zip [21] => zlib [22] => libxml [23] => dom [24] => PDO [25] => bz2 [26] => SimpleXML [27] => wddx [28] => xml [29] => xmlreader [30] => xmlwriter [31] => apache2handler [32] => Phar [33] => curl [34] => com_dotnet [35] => fileinfo [36] => gd [37] => gettext [38] => gmp [39] => intl [40] => imap [41] => ldap [42] => mbstring [43] => exif [44] => mysql [45] => mysqli [46] => pdo_mysql [47] => pdo_sqlite [48] => soap [49] => sockets [50] => sqlite3 [51] => xmlrpc [52] => xsl [53] => mhash [54] => Zend OPcache [55] => xdebug )
```

Comment: Can you add your extension config section (sqlsrv) from phpinfo?

Comment: Hi @mim, I can't find that anywhere on phpinfo - where should it be?

Comment: @mim - question edited; they don't seem to have been loaded. How can I resolve this?

Comment: check php.ini,The code below show where the php drivers are residing:
`; On windows:
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`

Comment: All PHP Extensions have to be Thread Safe in WAMPServer. So remove all those `NTS` versions

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your GUI marks them as "installed" means little. The GUI tool might *think* they are installed, while they are not. For PHP to use extensions, they need to be specified either in the PHP.INI file, or in a file loaded by PHP.INI. Also, it is possible that if they're specified in both, only one is actually working.

Using `phpinfo()` you can retrieve the location of `php.ini`, which you can open using any \n-compliant text editor (so, Wordpad, not Notepad) to see what is *really* there.

Then you need to check how it's loading the extensions.

For example phpinfo might say:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/common/modules
```

Here it means that you ned to check that PHP.ini, plus all INI files in the directory `modules`. Your paths will vary, of course.

Either in PHP.INI or in, say, modules/SQLSERV.INI (name is ignored, but the extension must be .ini), you will need to have something like

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Then, these DLLs (your DLLs might be different, and you'll have one for each driver you install) will need to be there, and be the correct version. You should get a message if this is not so, but the message might be lost in some logfile somewhere. So you'll need to check the configuration and see whether such a message is displayed.

In a pinch, you can try and set a **wrong** DLL to see whether that elicits some recognizable error behaviour. If it does, you'll be sure that the line is parsed, and therefore *not* having that behaviour means the line is okay.

Answer (score -2):

The MSSQL extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later. SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft: » http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Original Answer :

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736601/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-xampp-htdocs)

Comment: Those are the ones I'm using. My setup is exactly as per that question.

Comment: create a file with `php_info()` you will get extension list.

Comment: Do you mean `phpinfo();`? I already have one, can't see them listed.

Comment: Question edited; they don't seem to have been loaded. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you working locally,if yes.then install SQLExpress locally.