# want to connect sql database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

it gives Error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
>
> Filename:/home2/avyat/public_html/doitcenter_test/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php#install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php-1

Answer (score 0):

> The MSSQL extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3
>   or later. SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from
>   Microsoft: »
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

reference from : [see here to step by step how to resolve issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736601/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-xampp-htdocs)

Comment: So what you are basically saying is this is a Dup otherwise this is just plagiarism of the answer you quote in your answer

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the extension is properly loaded in **phpinfo();** (something like **sqlsrv** should appear). If not, the extension isn't properly loaded. You also need to restart apache after installing an extension.

Common glitches include:

1. Edit the wrong php.ini file (that's typical with bundles); the right
   a path is shown in **phpinfo()**
2. Forget to restart Apache
3. Not be able to see the startup errors; those should show up in Apache logs, but you can also use the command line to diagnose it, e.g.:

   php -d display_startup_errors=1 -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors -c "C:\Path\To\php.ini" -m

Answer (score 0):

You have add the SQLSRV php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll drivers.

Add to the php.ini file

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

or

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```