# extension of php.ini in xampp does not work in case of only 'sqlsrv.dll'

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, xampp, sqlsrv

```
PHP: 5.6.4
Computer: 64 bits
Thread Safety: Enable
SQL Sever 2017
```

[image]

[image]

I add `'extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll', 'extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll'` in `php.ini` like

```
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
**extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Additionally, I checked php version, computer bits, and thread-safety between xampp and ddl.
I also tried adding `'php_sqlsrv_55/52_nts.dll' and php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` in `32 bits`.

the result is like

[image]

For your information, it worked well when I added `'extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll'`.
I followed the best answer in

> [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736601/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-xampp-htdocs)

Comment: Probbaly you need to install an appropriate ODBC Driver - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488.

Comment: thank you for your answer...but I think I already installed odbc driver.....

Comment: Take a look at [Suppport Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15) and follow these steps: 1) You need to download version 3.2 of PHP Driver for SQl Server (for PHP 5.6.4). 2} You need to download and install ODBC Driver 11 (this is not a PHP extension). 3) Version 3.2 of the driver doesn't support SQL Server 2017 (but this is not your problem here). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much....I modified my odbc driver version but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: Is it possible for 'Configure Command' to cause the problem???