# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I am using:

- XAMPP version 3.3.0 with php version 8.1.10
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> sqlsrv_connect() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\treasureDoc\php\otentifikasi.php:5 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\treasureDoc\index.html(45): otentifikasi('', '') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\treasureDoc\php\otentifikasi.php on line 5

This is what I have tried so far:

- download and extract file from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 to c:\xampp\php\ext
- download and install odbc driver 18 for sql server
- i added extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll and extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll to the php.ini file

I've tried everything mentioned here [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736601/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-c-xampp-htdocs)

Comment: FYI, the version of SSMS you are using is irrelevant here; it's just an IDE like application for use with SQL Server, it has nothing to do with the problem of trying to connect to a SQL Server with php/xampp.

Comment: Did you read all [this page you mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) including the **See Also**